# Parse.com Android Unity Nothing works not even the test object

Tags: c#, android, parse-platform, unity-game-engine

I have just started using Parse.com On Unity 5.0.0fb, and after getting my application to work with Parse on Unity Editor I decided to try it on my Mobile to find nothing works. I have checked the APK and Parse is inside it but when I try anything it does not work.

I have tested this with a Test APK with nothing but parse and the test script attached to a button and it also does not work.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using Parse;


public class ScriptTest : MonoBehaviour {
 public UnityEngine.UI.Text Mytext;
 string mytext;
 // Use this for initialization




 public void MySpecial () {
 ParseObject testObject = new ParseObject("TestObject");
 testObject["foo"] = "bar";
 testObject.SaveAsync();
 mytext = "Saved";
 Mytext.text = mytext;
 Debug.Log (mytext);
 }

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {

 }
}
```

It will not do anything the button will click it will say saved on my text but when I check parse TestObject nothing will be there. Is there something im missing in my build?

I have made sure stripping is also disabled.

[image: How my build looks]

This works 100% in editor just not in Android I have no idea or way to test iOS.

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same problem, using Unity 5.1 and Parse Unity SDK 1.5.1. It works perfectly in the editor but not on Android.

Here's my code :

```
    ParseObject _localPlayer = new ParseObject();

    Task query = _localPlayer.SaveAsync();

    while (!query.IsCompleted)
        yield return null;

    if (!query.IsFaulted && !query.IsCanceled)
    {
        Debug.Log ("Player successfully created!");
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Failed to create player...");
    }
```

The task generated with the SaveAsync() request doesn't seem to end at all (isCompleted is never true) so it becomes an infinite loop, and the actual cloud operation is not performed (no trace on the Parse dashboard). There doesn't seem to be any exception thrown and the device log doesn't show anything.

I'm really stuck at this point and haven't be able to find any solution anywhere on the web so far. :(

Answer (score 1):

Using Parse SDK 1.3.2 "fixes" the issue.

-> https://parse.com/downloads/windows/Parse/1.3.2

Looks like a big fat regression. ;)

Answer (score 1):

Going back to Parse Unity SDK 1.3.2 worked for me.

LogOutAsync() had to be replaced with LogOut(), but that was the only change I had to make in my code.

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this problem is to reimport project settings from their blank project. It will fix any build problems you have.

Answer (score 0):

The bug report, for those who would like to be kept informed:
https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/1623483557935932/